# subsamplingscaleimageview clean pins image

Tags: android, imageview, scale, subsampling

I want to delete from my PinView all pins when changing background image.
I add the pins by inserting them into a coordinate ArrayList and pin image and everything works correctly.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you already have the Points in an arrayList. Use the `setPin` function from below( it also needs a "name" for the point, you can simply add the index of the point from arrayList as name using `String.valueOf(//you index);` as the name of pin). Now when you want to remove the points, just run a simple for loop for the arrayList, and remove all the elements. Give it a try.

P.S. The code also contains few other functions, feel free to delete them if you don't need it.

```
public class PinView extends SubsamplingScaleImageView {

private ArrayList<PointF> sPin = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> pinNames = new ArrayList<>();
private Bitmap pin;
private final float scale=1.5f;

public PinView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public PinView(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(context, attr);
    initialise();
}

public boolean setPin(PointF sPin, String name) {
    if (pinNames.contains(name)){
        return false;
    } else {
        this.sPin.add(sPin);
        pinNames.add(name);
        initialise();
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}

public PointF getPin(String name) {

    return sPin.get(pinNames.indexOf(name));
}

public boolean removePin(String name){
    if (pinNames.contains(name)){
        sPin.remove(pinNames.indexOf(name));
        pinNames.remove(name);
        System.out.println("Removed pin named : "+name);
        initialise();
        invalidate();
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("No such pins : "+name);
        initialise();
        invalidate();
        return false;
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> getPinNames(){
    return pinNames;
}

private void initialise() {
    float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    pin = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.squarered);
    float w = (density/420f) * pin.getWidth();
    float h = (density/420f) * pin.getHeight();
    pin = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(pin, (int)w, (int)h, true);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Don't draw pin before image is ready so it doesn't move around during setup.
    if (!isReady()) {
        return;
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    for (PointF point : sPin){
        if (point != null && pin != null) {
            PointF vPin = sourceToViewCoord(point);
            float vX = vPin.x - (pin.getWidth()/2);
            float vY = vPin.y - pin.getHeight();
            canvas.drawBitmap(pin, vX, vY, paint);
        }
    }
}
public void doAnimationWithTime(PointF target)
{

    //System.out.println("Width : " + this.getSWidth() + " height : " + this.getSHeight());
    SubsamplingScaleImageView.AnimationBuilder animationBuilder = this.animateScaleAndCenter(scale, target);
    animationBuilder.withDuration(700).withEasing(SubsamplingScaleImageView.EASE_OUT_QUAD).withInterruptible(true).start();
}

public boolean isPinVisibleOnImage(String name)
{
    boolean result = false;
    for(int i=0;i<pinNames.size();i++)
    {
        if(pinNames.get(i).equals(name.trim()))
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

}